# Can't remove table tr properly in each loop using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

my for loop is creating this at run time using jquery

```
<tr id="auctionLocation_0"></tr>
<tr id="auctionLocation_0"></tr>
<tr id="auctionLocation_0"></tr>
<tr id="auctionLocation_1"></tr>
<tr id="auctionLocation_1"></tr>
<tr id="auctionLocation_1"></tr>
```

and I'm removing it using jquery each loop and my code is

```
function testing() {
    var current = 0;
    $("#user").each(function() {
        $("#user").find("tr[id='auctionLocation_"+current+"']").remove();
        current++;
    });
}
```

OR

```
function testing() {
     $("#user").each(function(i, v) {
         $("#user").find("tr[id='auctionLocation_"+i+"']").remove();
        });
}
```

its only remove `0` index not `1` index so how I could do it?

thats my creating code

```
var counterForLocationsField = 1;
var auctionCompanyLocationArray = data.auctionCompanyLocationArray;
for(var auctionCompanyLocationLoop = 0; auctionCompanyLocationLoop < auctionCompanyLocationArray.length; auctionCompanyLocationLoop++) {
var completeTr = "<tr id='auctionLocation_"+auctionCompanyLocationLoop+"'><td>Location Name "+counterForLocationsField+"</td><td>"+auctionCompanyLocationArray[auctionCompanyLocationLoop]["auctionLocationName"]+"</td> <td>Location Address "+counterForLocationsField+"</td><td>"+auctionCompanyLocationArray[auctionCompanyLocationLoop]["auctionLocationAddress"]+"</td></tr>";
completeTr += "<tr id='auctionLocation_"+auctionCompanyLocationLoop+"'><td>Location City "+counterForLocationsField+"</td><td>"+auctionCompanyLocationArray[auctionCompanyLocationLoop]["auctionLocationCity"]+"</td> <td>Location State "+counterForLocationsField+"</td><td>"+auctionCompanyLocationArray[auctionCompanyLocationLoop]["auctionLocationState"]+"</td></tr>";
completeTr += "<tr id='auctionLocation_"+auctionCompanyLocationLoop+"'><td>Location Zipcode "+counterForLocationsField+"</td><td>"+auctionCompanyLocationArray[auctionCompanyLocationLoop]["auctionLocationZipcode"]+"</td> <td>Location Phone "+counterForLocationsField+"</td><td>"+auctionCompanyLocationArray[auctionCompanyLocationLoop]["auctionLocationPhone"]+"</td></tr>";
$(completeTr).insertBefore("#lastRow");
counterForLocationsField++;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using IDs more than once?...

Comment: Do not use same id for multiple elements.

Comment: Do you know it is invalid way of writing markup which leads to errors just like you are getting currently.

Comment: can I use class instead of id in tr so I think Its remove all tr

Comment: I must have to show three tr based on my database record so what I have to do?

Comment: Do you want to remove all trs? What are you trying to remove?

Comment: And please don't give me down vote so next time I couldn't post a question

Answer (score 0):

As you select the id user, the loop only loops once. Ids are unique.
You can use the starts with selector. 
`$("tr[id^='auctionLocation_']").remove();`
No loop needed. If you want to loop use `$("tr[id^='auctionLocation_']").each()`.

Comment: I must have to show three tr based on my database record so what I have to do?

Comment: And please don't give me down vote so next time I couldn't post a question.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use same ids for different elements. Id must be unique in the page.

Use class instead, like:

```
<tr class="auctionLocation_0"></tr>
<tr class="auctionLocation_0"></tr>
<tr class="auctionLocation_0"></tr>
<tr class="auctionLocation_1"></tr>
<tr class="auctionLocation_1"></tr>
<tr class="auctionLocation_1"></tr>
```

And when you want to remove them, just do the above, without loops:

```
$('tr.auctionLocation_0').remove()
```

Comment: Well, I still think that you should change your ids for classes, but the code is yours.. :)